# Existing column unrecognized by Delta merge

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake

Sample of my data I'm working on:

**Source**

```
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
|store_id |type                |store_status |        name        |    owner           |owner_code    |store_asOfDate    |
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
|  123    |type                |not_active   |name                |xyz                 |    xyz       |        2024-03-20|
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

**Target**

```
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
|store_id |type                |store_status |        name        |    owner           |owner_code    |store_asOfDate    |
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
|  123    |type                |active       |name                |xyz                 |    xyz       |        2024-03-15|
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

**Code snippet**

```
target_dt.alias("target") \
    .merge(
        source=df_trusted.alias("source"),
        condition="target.store_id=source.store_id AND target.store_status=source.store_status"
    ) \
    .whenNotMatchedBySourceUpdate(
        set={
            "store_status": F.col("source.store_status"),
            "store_asOfDate": F.col("source.store_asOfDate")
        }
    ) \
    .execute()
```

**Expected behaviour**:

- target's row `store_status` and `store_asOfDate` are updated.

**Target (after merge/upsert)**

```
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
|store_id |type                |store_status |        name        |    owner           |owner_code    |store_asOfDate    |
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
|  123    |type                |not_active   |name                |xyz                 |    xyz       |        2024-03-20|
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

**Currently**, error is thrown:

```
24/03/21 14:06:29 ERROR Error occured in my_method() method: [DELTA_MERGE_UNRESOLVED_EXPRESSION] Cannot resolve source.store_id in UPDATE condition given columns....
```

Please suggest where I can debug further for root cause.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal is to have a DeltaTable at the end of:

```
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
|store_id |type                |store_status |        name        |    owner           |owner_code    |store_asOfDate    |
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
|  123    |type                |not_active   |name                |xyz                 |    xyz       |        2024-03-15|
+---------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

Let me write your code a bit more advanced as you are then able to set the columns by a list in your merge statement. The `event` alias is the table that is already existing as it contains event records. The `updates` alias is the table that should contain the rows to update.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

merge_keys = ["store_id"]
cols_to_update = ["store_status", "store_asOfDate"]
(
    target_dt.alias("events")
    .merge(
        source=df_trusted.alias("updates"),
        condition=" AND ".join([f"events.`{x}` = updates.`{x}`" for x in merge_keys])
    )
    .whenMatchedUpdate(set={x: f"updates.`{x}`" for x in cols_to_update})
    .execute()
)
```

Also please do not write python code with line separators of type `\` as they are deprecated. Instead use parentheses or pre-commit hooks with black formatter.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo on my end. `store_asOfDate == 2024-03-15` at target, should become `2024-03-20` due to updated value. Also my merge is done based on two columns, not only `store_id`.

Comment: please add the expected dataframe. your expectations are unclear what should get updated. i.e. I dont know if the store_status should also get updated or not at the end.